# .htaccess (mod_rewrite) recursion in handling %{HTTP_HOST}

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My aim is to simulate virtual hosts using mod_rewrite in .htaccess such that http://dog.animal.com maps internally to WEBROOT/public_html/dog/ , cat.animal.com maps internally to WEBROOT/public_html/cat/ , where dog and cat are established usernames on the system.

I have (in an `.htaccess` in WEBROOT):

```
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}                 ^[^.]+\.animal\.com$
RewriteRule   ^(.+)                        %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
RewriteRule   ^([^.]+)\.animal\.com(.*) /public_html/$1$2
```

But on requesting dog.animal.com I receive the following loop

> Forbidden. You don't have permission to access
>   /public_html/dogpublic_html/dogpublic_html/dogpublic_html/dogpublic_html/.....
>   etc etc

Clearly I am overlooking something stupidly obvious. I'd appreciate any pointers!

(I should say that in the above example, there are A records in teh zone file for the two subdomains)

Answer (score 0):

In your second rewrite rule, you use /public_html which refers to root. Try removing the starting / or put the full path with WEBROOT

Comment: I've tried modifying the replacement string, but always it gets repeated. Somehow, somewhere my RewriteCond is being matched again, hence the repetition of the filepath. I need to figure out how to have it stop after the first iteration. Removing 'root' does not affect this. Thanks, though.

Comment: Maybe a hack, but try to put a [L] at the end of the last rewrite to stop the rewriting

Comment: I've read rules for rewrite are slightly different in .htaccess. By using a condition with HTTP_HOST, you do not need first rewrite rule, which add HTTP_POST in front of full URL

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to Apache's logs-- I'm working on a remote machine to which I have very limited access. Hence the .htaccess route; otherwise I'd just have virtualHosted my way through the problem in httpd.conf

Comment: So remove the first rewriting rule should fix it